# A functional of a Lévy process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

Does anyone know if there are any papers/results on functionals of the type :

$$\int_0^tp(X_s)ds$$

where $X$ is a Lévy process and $p$ is a polynomial. For example, is the distribution of such an object known when $p(x) = x^2$ (in general, or for some special models) ?

Comment: @ Billy Pilgrim : What kind of results are you looking for ? The question is I am afraid a bit too general, and the only thing that comes to my mind is hum Itô's lemma ... best regards.

Comment: No particular results, just curious if there was a systematic study of this object like say for the exponential functional. My search found nothing, and I was curious if the Internet could do better :).